# Wordpress Plugin cant activate

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

i made this custom plugin for my web agency customers.
they install it on their wp site, and go under setup, and accept that we can acesses their site.
Then it creates a user called "Nimbus Nordic" with the passcode "Ymw.1144*" and i get a email confirming they have given us acsess, they can also delete the user under the menu.

The issue is when i install the plugin there is no issue, but when i try to activate it, it just reloads the page and dosent activate. No error messeges.

here is a link to the code: https://github.com/yassinayoub/WPsupport

Comment: Enable debugging in WordPress by adding the following lines to your wp-config.php file: `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );
define( 'WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', true );` This will display any errors or warnings on the screen when the plugin is activated.

Comment: You provided a private repo link so your only bet is to do what @MohammadHosseinBeshavard wrote above

Comment: @WisdomIghofose I made the repo public, and did the debugging, this is what i get                   Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'function' (T_FUNCTION), expecting variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /var/www/bolig-greve.dk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/nimbus-nordic-fjernadgang/nimbusnordic.php on line 42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going through the GitHub code you must have mistakenly deleted some part of the code, check line 39 `$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $`

Should be :
`$user_id = wp_create_user( $username, $password);`

Comment: Thank you so much i have just fixed the missing code, but now i get an error on last line. When i delete that line i get a error on the new last line take a look at this screenshot;  https://ibb.co/2Kh8RFW

Comment: Merge my pull request and you will be good